# Why the below dataframe map to dataframe fails?

Tags: scala

I have a dummy dataframe as follows:

```
val df = Seq((Seq("abc", "cde"), 19, "red, abc"), (Seq("eefg", "efa", "efb"), 192, "efg, efz efz")).toDF("names", "age", "color")
```

I have created an sqlContext as follows:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);
```

I have also imported implicits:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
```

However, when I try to do the following it fails:

```
scala> val d2 = df.map(x => x).toDF


<console>:30: error: Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
       val d2 = df.map(x => x).toDF
                      ^
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm not familiar with dataframe/spark stuff, but the error suggests importing `spark.implicits._`. Have you tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.RowEncoder

scala> val df = Seq((Seq("abc", "cde"), 19, "red, abc"), (Seq("eefg", "efa", "efb"), 192, "efg, efz efz")).toDF("names", "age", "color")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [names: array<string>, age: int ... 1 more field]

scala> implicit val encoder = RowEncoder(df.schema)
encoder: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = class[names[0]: array<string>, age[0]: int, color[0]: string]

scala> val df2 = df.map(x => x).toDF
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [names: array<string>, age: int ... 1 more field]

scala> df2.collect
res0: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([WrappedArray(abc, cde),19,red, abc], [WrappedArray(eefg, efa, efb),192,efg, efz efz])
```

Comment: Could you please give some more info on the encoders? and why it is required? Also, please give some info on the performance impact on bigdata. Thanks

Comment: Encoders are used to convert scala Types to/from the internal Spark SQL representation. I guess there is no real performance issue unless you write your own incredibly inefficient Encoders. BTW,do you realise that `.map(x => x)` doesn't actually do anything useful.

Comment: yes, .map(x => x) does nothing. I was trying to do some operation on x here originally but was getting this exception. So I tested with this trivial operation.